# Keras model gives different predictions every time on machine

Tags: tensorflow, keras

The below code loads a tensorflow/keras model and its weights.

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import model_from_json


json_file = open('./mymodel.json', 'r')
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()

loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
loaded_model.load_weights("./mymodelweights.h5")
print("Loaded model from disk")


print(newmodel.predict(test_input))
```

The code works perfectly on 2 out of 3 machines that I tested it on. However, on the third machine it gives a different prediction every time I run the above code. I've been able to pin point the problem down to the first layer, which is `tensorflow.keras.layers.Conv2D`, it results in a different output every time on the third machine but not the first two.

I would appreciate some help in solving this problem.

Comment: Have you checked various versions consistency? 
Less likely - is there a single mymodelweights.h5 as well as mymodel.json ?

Comment: Yes, I have an identical environment on all machines, and there is a single json and h5 file.

Comment: I am not able to replicate your issue, can you share standalone code to replicate your issue and system specifications? so that we can try to help you. Thanks!